# Using regex with special characters to find a match in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I am extracting a string and need to check whether it follows a particular pattern

> `<![any word]>`

if so I need to replace it with "". I am trying the following code

```
string1 = "<![if support]> hello"
string = re.sub(re.compile("<![.*?]>"),"",string1)
print(string)
```

But I am getting the output as

```
<![if support]> hello
```

I wish to get the output as hello. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[` and `]` are treated as meta characters in regex. You'll need to escape them:

```
In [1]: re.sub(re.compile("<!\[.*?\]>"), "", "<![if support]> hello")
Out[1]: ' hello'
```

---

As a [simplification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45325917/using-regex-with-special-characters-to-find-a-match-in-python/45325963?noredirect=1#comment77614324_45325963) (courtesy Wiktor Stribiżew), you can escape just the first left paren, shortening your regex to `"<!\[.*?]>"`.

Comment: `]` is not a special regex operator outside a character class. `r"<!\[.*?]>"` is enough.